# Creating ORM mappings over subqueries of a table

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use SQLAlchemy in a situation where I have a one to many table construct and but I essentially want to create a one to one mapping between tables using a subquery.

For example

```
class User:
    __tablename__='user'
    userid = Column(Integer)
    username = Column(String)

class Address:
    __tablename__='address'
    userid = Column(Integer)
    address= Column(String)
    type= Column(String)
```

In this case the type column of Address includes strings like "Home", "Work" etc. I would like the output to look something like this

[image]

I tried using a subquery where I tried

```
session.query(Address).filter(Address.type =="Home").subquery("HomeAddress")
```

and then joining against that but then I lose ORM "entity" mapping.

How can I subquery but retain the ORM attributes in the results object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use a subquery. The join condition is not limited to foreign key against primary key:

```
home_address = aliased(Address, "home_address")
work_address = aliased(Address, "work_address")
session.query(User) \
       .join(home_address, and_(User.userid == home_address.userid,
                                home_address.type == "Home")) \
       .join(work_address, and_(User.userid == work_address.userid,
                                work_address.type == "Work")) \
       .with_entities(User, home_address, work_address)
```

Comment: This works but would be annoying would require N types for each. Not asking you to do this but is it possible to put this into a loop and define a list of all values I care about?

Comment: @canyon289 Certainly. There's nothing preventing you from adding joins to the query in a loop.

Comment: Thanks Univerio. Much appreciated